# parsing integers in python into a command for another software

Tags: python, parsing

I want to write

```
vol_id = geom.get_owning_volume("surface", 12)
```

and I have S=12 on the fly during large code execution so I use

```
S=12
vol_id = geom.get_owning_volume("surface", "%d") %(S)
```

which gives me an error

```
TypeError: in method 'get_owning_volume', argument 2 of type 'int'
```

I have used the variation

```
S=12
vol_id = geom.get_owning_volume("surface", "%d" %(S))
```

this gives the same error

why I cannot parse the integer 12 to the desired place! any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://cubit.sandia.gov/public/13.2/help_manual/WebHelp/appendix/python/namespace_cubit_interface.htm#get_owning_volume) that I found, `get_owning_volume` takes a string and an integer, and you already have an integer, so there's no need to convert it:

```
vol_id = geom.get_owning_volume("surface", S)
```

From the comments it looks like `S` is actually a string, and you want an integer, then this should work:

```
vol_id = geom.get_owning_volume("surface", int(S))
```

Comment: @Bill,  why should I do to parse an int  since my version generates this command from another script!

Answer (score 1):

The `%` operator is for interpolating into strings, not into Python code.  Your example is trying to pass the string `"%d"` where the function expects a number; no wonder it fails!

In your case, just put the variable `S` where you need it:

```
S=12
vol_id = geom.get_owning_volume("surface", S)
```

Comment: why should I do to parse an int then?